# Detect screen lock in Node WebKit

Tags: node.js, windows, node-webkit

I'm developing an application for Windows using node WebKit and want to perform some tasks when the user locks the screen like stopping some timers. Is it possible in node WebKit. I looked into screen geometry but it seems to offer only detecting number of screens mainly for multi screen apps.

Thanks

Comment: Is this meant for Windows, or platform agnostic? Either way, I'm wondering if you can listen for a lock-screen event broadcasted by the OS.

Comment: If it's only meant for Windows, I'd look into how to subscribe to Windows Events, and track down the lock-screen event. I'm new to Node right now, but it seems reasonable that you could at the very least use something like emscripten to make use of event subscribing compiled directly into javascript if it's not already supported in an easier way (probably is, btw).

Comment: @Harshad. Were you able to get this done. I also require this functionality in node webkit. If you were able to get this done can you please share the answer.

Answer (score 2):

[Use the API](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CSDetectWindowsSessionState-f27d0321) function [`OpenInputDesktop`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684309(VS.85).aspx) from the library `user32.dll`. The call can be made through the [`node-ffi`](https://github.com/node-ffi/node-ffi) module:

```
var FFI = require('node-ffi');

// user32.dll
var user32 = new FFI.Library('user32', {
   'OpenInputDesktop': [
      'IntPtr', [ 'int32', 'bool', 'int32' ]
   ]
});
```