# How to detect from node.js that current windows user session is locked?

Tags: node.js, windows

Is it possible to detect from node that current session is locked?
By simple user, not administrator.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect screen lock in Node WebKit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34446237/detect-screen-lock-in-node-webkit)